# Неверно распознается значение параметра в SQL запросе

Tags: sql, sql-server

На примере простой таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE [Test]([id] int NOT NULL Identity,[Name] varchar(5) NULL)
```

```
INSERT INTO [Test]([Name]) VALUES('1-0-0'),('1-1-0'),('1-2-0')
```

Пишу запрос на выбор первых двух значений:

```
SELECT * FROM [Test] WHERE [Name] like '1-[0,1]-0'
```

Все ок, возвращает два значения.

Проблемы начинаются, если попытаться то же самое сделать через параметр:

```
DECLARE @Param varchar(7)
SET @Param='1-[0,1]-0'

SELECT * FROM [Test] WHERE [Name] like @Param
```

Выборка пуста. 
Как можно заставить запрос работать с параметром с квадратными скобками? Другие подстановочные знаки (например, % и _) работают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в реальности вы выполняете такой поиск:

```
SELECT * FROM [Test] WHERE [Name] like '1-[0,1]'

DECLARE @Param varchar(7) -- 7 символов
```

ЗЫ: Запятая в квадратных скобках не нужна.

Comment: Ох, точно. :D Спасибо.